# How to display one imageview and when it is clicked next image view is to appear

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to have an imageview displayed randomly from 5 imageviews then when user clicks the displayed imageview I want another imageview to appear and the process is to be repeated until count reaches 5, but the code displays multiple imageviews at a time.

My code:

```
public class Gamepage extends Activity 
{
    ImageView img,img1,img2,img3,img4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.trygame);

        img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        img1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        img2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        img3=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        img4=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
        int choose;
        int count=0;
            choose=(int) (Math.random()*5);
            while(count!=5)
            {
            switch(choose)
        {
        case 1:

        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast toast= Toast.makeText(Gamepage.this, "caught!! ",     200);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT, 10,10);
            toast.show();

            img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;

        }
    });
            //choose=(int) (Math.random()*5);
            //count++;
    break;
    case 2:
        img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        img1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast toast= Toast.makeText(Gamepage.this,     "caught!! ", 200);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT, 10,10);
                toast.show();
                img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            }
        });
        //choose=(int) (Math.random()*5);
        //count++;
        break;
    case 3:

        img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        img2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast toast= Toast.makeText(Gamepage.this, "caught!! ", 200);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT, 10,10);
                toast.show();
                img2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            }
        });
        //choose=(int) (Math.random()*5);
        //count++;
        break;
    case 4:

        img3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        img3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast toast= Toast.makeText(Gamepage.this, "caught!! ", 200);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT, 10,10);
                toast.show();
                img3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            }
        });
        //choose=(int) (Math.random()*5);
        //count++;
        break;
    case 5:

        img4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        img4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast toast= Toast.makeText(Gamepage.this, "caught!! ", 200);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT, 10,10);
                toast.show();
                img4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;

            }
        });
        //choose=(int) (Math.random()*5);
    //  count++;
        break;
        default:
            img4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            img4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast toast= Toast.makeText(Gamepage.this, "caught!! ", 200);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT, 10,10);
                    toast.show();
                    img4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    return true;

                }
            });
            //choose=(int) (Math.random()*5);
            //count++;
            break;

    }
        choose=(int) (Math.random()*5);
        count++;
        }


}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the visibility true and false like this is really bad design. You can instead create one ImageView and and change image resource using the "setImageResource()".

If, as I understood, the functionality of clicking the image is only to show another random image, you can do the following:

1- In your XML layout, create one "ImageView".

2- In your activity java code, create an array (preferebly an arraylist) with your images resources.

```
ArrayList<int> myImages = new ArrayList<int>();
myImages.add(R.drawable.firstimage);
myImages.add(R.drawable.secondImage);
```

3- Instead of writing all these listeners and the long switch case, use this simple code:

```
int rnd = Math.random()*5;
int counter = 0;
public void onClick(View v){
   if(counter<5){
      img.setImageResource(myImages.get(rnd));
      counter++;
   }
   else{
      //do whatever you want
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Did you set the visibility of all ImageView to INVISIBLE before looping?
- As the loop can be run very fast, you may not see the result this way. Try putting Thread.sleep(3000) at the end of the loop so that it will slow the loop down.

Comment: yes i did set all of them to invisible  thread.sleep is not helping

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the solution. It works here... Try this:

```
public class GamePage extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private int count=0;
private ImageView img;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.trygame);

    img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_bitmap_drawable1);
    img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (count<5){
                int choose=(int) (Math.random()*5);
                switch(choose){
                    case 1:
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_bitmap_drawable1);
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_bitmap_drawable2);
                    break;
                    case 3:
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_bitmap_drawable3);
                    break;
                    case 4:
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_bitmap_drawable4);
                    break;
                    case 5:
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_bitmap_drawable5);
                    break;
                    default:
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_bitmap_drawable5);
                    break;
                }
                Toast toast= Toast.makeText(TextViewEffectsActivity.this, "caught!! ",     200);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT, 10,10);
                toast.show();
            }
            count++;
        }
    });
}
}
```

**trygame.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You don't need to have 5 ImageViews... Tell me if it works for you...

Comment: does not work...the nxt image view is not displayed on clicking the image view that is displayed initailly..my original code works this way if i remove while loop that is enclosing switch. Thanku for ur effort though

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/forest_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:src="@drawable/duckfinal" android:layout_gravity="top|left" android:clickable="true" android:visibility="invisible"/>

Comment: <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:src="@drawable/duckfinal" android:clickable="true" android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/duckfinal" android:layout_gravity="end" android:clickable="true" android:visibility="invisible"/>

Comment: <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/duckfinal" android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:src="@drawable/duckfinal" android:layout_gravity="start" android:clickable="true" android:visibility="invisible"/>

Comment: <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/duckfinal" android:clickable="true" android:visibility="invisible"/>

"
    
</LinearLayout>

Comment: this is whole trygame.xml file

Comment: @PrateekGupta Answer edited. Don't put code in comments, you should edit your question instead...

Answer (score 0):

I have a sulotion here:

-You put your Images in to a Array List

-Randomize your List

-Get the first image in your List to show

-Set Listener or Time out to change to next image.